# EntityFramework creates/runs migrations using parameterless DataContext instance

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, console-application, entity-framework-migrations

I wanted to test some EF features within a .NET 7 console app. I have my database context class, initially only providing the constructor that takes the context options

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Review> Reviews { get; set; }

    public DataContext()
    {
    }

    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(CONNECTION_STRING);
    }
}
```

However the migrations command line tool was complaining that it could not instantiate the class, so I've seen people suggest adding a default constructor. This works, however, this implies overriding `OnConfiguring` in order to provide the connection string, which, as far as I can tell has to be hard-coded.

Is there a way to inject the options (forcing the use of the second constructor) when running migration commands? I'm basically trying to replicate this scenario from my entry file (`Program.cs`), where sensitive data is read from some config provider.

```
var connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString");

var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>()
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .Options;

var context = new DataContext(contextOptions);
```

Comment: Implement `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<DataContext>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your configuration is in appsettings.json, you can add this `CreateDbContext` function on the `DataContext` class:

```
public DataContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
    var connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString");

    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<WcsContext>();
    builder.UseSqlServer(applicationDbConnection);

    return new DataContext(builder.Options);
}
```

Comment: This assumes that your configuration is in appsettings.json (it doesn't have to be, other configuration systems exist) and ignores the environment (what if my connection string is in `appsettings.Development.json`?).

Comment: @CodeCaster yes, it's nowhere near a production level environment. It's a console app that's oblivious to what `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is currently set to.

Comment: @CodeCaster: you're right, it was an example, maybe it's better to clarify this point on my asnwer. Thank you.